# Domain Driven Design - Aggregate Root and Nested Aggregate Invariants

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core

I've come to a bit of an impasse with the best way to implement a DDD problem, and am hoping for some advice from those with more experience, please.

I have a `RecipeCollection`, which has a collection of type `Recipe` (as you might expect). The abbreviated code looks like this:

```
public class RecipeCollection : IEntity<RecipeCollectionId>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly RecipeCollectionId id = new();
    private readonly List<RecipeId> recipeIds = new();

    public void AddRecipe(RecipeId recipeId) { /* not sure what to do here! */ }
...
}

public class Recipe : IEntity<RecipId>
{
    public readonly string Name { get; private set; }
...
}
```

One of the business rules is that a `Recipe` cannot have the same `Name` within a `RecipeCollection`. The obvious place to enforce this invariant is within `RecipeCollection`, when adding a new `Recipe`. However, `RecipeCollection` only holds a list of `RecipeId`, not a list of `Recipe` itself.

Ideally, `RecipeCollection` would hold a collection of `Recipe`, which would make checking for duplicate `Recipe.Name` easy. However, `RecipeCollection` holds a collection of `RecipeId`. It does this to avoid potential problems such as loading a `RecipeCollection` from memory, which loads all its `Recipe`s, which each in turn load another collection, and so on, and before you know it, you've loaded the entire database. I know I could use lazy loading, but I may use a data store where this isn't possible, so I'm forced to hold a collection of `RecipeId`.

Is the best solution, in this case, to have the calling code, i.e. the command handler that retrieves the `RecipeCollection` from the repo, check there are no duplicated `Recipe` `Name`s before adding the `Recipe`? This would leak the business logic out of the Aggregate root in this instance, which is why I haven't committed to this solution. Or is there another solution/pattern I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Purely technically the obvious best solution is to let the database figure this out. Assuming there is a database and the number of recipes is unbounded, so we don't want to load all into memory or iterate every one. The database can probably already do this and probably much better.

If that is true, then we just have to figure out where the call should be. If it is up to the caller to do it, then obviously this logic is not encapsulated. Can be forgotten, duplicated, made poorly, etc.

I would expect it to be in `AddRecipe()`. It seemingly implements some use-case, so I would except it does everything necessary to fulfill it.

Comment: yes, good point, the database is best placed to recognise a duplicated recipe name. Normally, this would force the logic to live in the caller method, in the repo, or (if using an rdbms) by enforcing a unique constraint. Either way, the business logic is leaked.

Your comment has got me thinking, though. The caller, which has access to the repository, could pass a callback to `AddRecipe()`, which would return true/false as to whether the name already exists in the collection. Then, `AddRecipe()` can perform the check before adding the recipe.

Comment: If some portion of the logic leaks, maybe the design is not optimal? I don't know the specifics of your requirements, but maybe another design may fit better?

Comment: It's just a very simple design to demonstrate DDD. It's a `RecipeCollection` that holds a collection of `Recipe`, but I decided the `Recipe.Name` should be unique in a `RecipeCollection` - seems like a fairly common use case. I think changing the `RecipeCollection.AddRecipe(RecipeId recipeId)` method to be `AddRecipe(RecipeId recipeId, Func<RecipeId, RecipeCollectionId, bool> doesRecipeNameExistInCollection)` may be the best solution to ensure the business logic remains in the `RecipeCollection`. The caller will be responsible for providing a `Func` to fulfil the query.

Comment: @danwag, it is not uncommon that uniqueness business requirements "leak" to the repositories/database, because databases have the best tools to enforce those constraints with the least amount of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there another solution/pattern I'm missing?

You can push this problem out to the DB. But now your solution is dependent on the DB. And maybe that's fine. But there are alternatives.

> I'm forced to hold a collection of RecipeId.

Remember, references are tiny. Doesn't matter how big your recipe object is you can copy references to it into many data structures and still only have one copy of the recipe loaded into memory.

Which means just because you have a collection of `RecipeId`s that may have duplicates doesn't mean that's the only collection you can have.  Create `Recipes` and never let it get loaded or added to without validating. You can still have your other collection that doesn't check for whatever technical reason. But if `Recipes` is populated you know it's validated. You know there are no duplicate names in it.

With this approach you are free to store your recipes in text files because the bulk of your code doesn't know or care if there is the DB.

Comment: Thanks @candied_orange. The problem I can foresee is that `Recipe`s may have duplicate names, just not within a `RecipeCollection`. It may be a bit of a contrived example, but I'm sure it's a common use case to need to check some property of a child entity against other child entities / value objects.

Comment: @danwag it is a common use case. You seem to think every Recipe loaded must be a fully resolved deep copy. But if you can hold `RecipeId`s you can hold other Id's. More importantly you can certainly hold the fields you need to enforce your constraint.

Comment: I am having a hard time picturing how to have a Recipe collection of Recipes that aren't fully resolved. Could you point me to an example, please? Or, are you suggesting RecipeCollection would hold a collection of Recipe.Name for the specific purpose of addressing the duplicate name problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will be very useful if you examine the following sample design that Microsoft has given as best practice.

[eShopOnContainers Github Repo](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/OrderAggregate)

Note the relationship between the Order and OrderItem tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, it still has the question, what happens if `OrderItem` is very large, and an `Order` may contain 100s or 1000s of them? In their example, where an `Order` holds all of the `OrderItem`s, loading an `Order` could be very slow.

Comment: I think you can solve the problem by using data loading patterns. Please consider following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: Can you give some more explanation? This looks like a link-only answer.

Comment: This is a very broad topic and difficult to explain with an example. I suggest you take your time for courses on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhM0V2N1GpY